# Can PBIX file on Sharepoint be refreshed automatically using Power Automate at regular intervals?

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I have Power BI Dataset/Report saved on SharePoint or teams. I want to create a schedule to refresh and publish Dataset and Report file using Power Automate weekly. I could not find many resources online. So appreciate if anyone can provide the work instructions for this

I tried using "Refresh Power BI Dataset" in Power automate. It works only when person is logged on and fails when PC is shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

No, do this way instead:

1. Choose your source:

[image]

2. Publish to Power BI
3. Go into your Workspace settings and schedule an automatic refresh

[image]